# What is instance for update chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I'm trying to make reactive changed graph, so I change some value, then my computed ChartData() put it to component, but nothing works. I'm trying to use update() function, but I have no instance for it.
How can I use function as .update(), .destroy() for my LineChart when I have no instance for it? Can I get instance of graph? What's wrong?
I guess i have 2 methods for update it? Is it?

**Update:**
Actually I get instance, but problem still exist. Computed property doesn't update data in Line and update() does nothing.

```html
<template>
    <div class="graph__busManag">
      <Line ref="Graph" id="Chart" :data="ChartData" :options="options" :plugins="plugins" />

    </div>
</template>

<script>

import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";
ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs";

data() {
    return {
        data: ...something,
        option: ...somedata,

},
  computed: {
    ChartData() {
      return this.data; // Should update graph, but doesn't , despite the fact that it is constantly triggered
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.data.datasets.data = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
      this.data = {...this.data};

      const chartInstance = this.$refs.Graph.chart

      console.log(chartInstance);
      chartInstance.update(); // not working
      chartInstance.reset(); // not w
  },
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts The chapters of interest are "how to update chart" and "how to get the instance"

Comment: @Nikolay Already yes, thank you. But there is explained how to update chart with compoted property, mine doesn't work, neither does update after take instance

Comment: @Nikolay The computed property works fine when updating an object, and return needed data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the static method getChart to which you pass the id you have given your chart. Here you get the chart instance back to which you can call update:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

const chartInstance = Chart.getChart(ownChartId);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already did it, but I have two problem in my code, I edited it with mark 'Update'. Shortly, even on instance update doesn't work as computed. Do you know why?

Comment: Never really used chart.js with computed props in VUE, so what you can do is set the data directly by updating the data in the chartInstance itself as explained in the docs here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.1.1/developers/updates.html